# How pass android.media.Image to other plugin on Flutter

Tags: flutter, camera, flutter-plugin, google-mlkit, flutter-platform-channel

I added the Camera plugin to my flutter project. I need to send the image got through ImageStream (CameraImage) to MlKit face detection, but the android API requires android.media.Image.

I tried,

1. Convert the CameraImage to android.media.Image on my plugin, but, I can't extend the class because the constructor is only allowed at the package level.
2. Read from memory. But the ImageReader only accepts one ByteBuffer(or byte array) and CameraImage has three planes (each of them with a ByteBuffer).

How can I convert the CameraImage to android.media.Image or pass the value directly from the Camera Plugin?

My last option is: create my own camera plugin with face detection. But I think there is a better solution

(PD: I cannot use firebase_ml_vision to avoid the use of Google Services)